# insert new row with auto incremental id is not added as last entry in the database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL - MyIsam table called `links` with the following structure

```
| field      | type         | null | predefined       | extra          |
|------------|--------------|------|------------------|----------------|
| id         | int(11)      | no   | none             | auto_increment |
| link       | varcar(2083) | no   | none             | none           |
| created_at | timestamp    | no   | curret_timestamp | none           |
| origin     | varcar(100)  | no   | none             | none           |
```

my insert statement is

```
public function createLink($user_id, $link, $origin) {        
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO links(link, origin) VALUES(?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $link, $origin);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();

        if ($result) {
            // link row created
            // now assign the link to user
            $new_link_id = $this->conn->insert_id;
            $res = $this->createUserLink($user_id, $new_link_id);
            if ($res) {
                // link created successfully
                return $new_link_id;
            } else {
                // user_link failed to create
                return NULL;
            }
        } else {
            // link failed to create
            return NULL;
        }
    }
```

unfortunately sometimes i get an unexpected behavior which i'm not totally able to reproduce.

[image: links table]

as you can see the rows with id 301 and 304 has been inserted between 286 and 293 as well as row with id 300 is between 298 and 296.

Since id is auto incremental, i would have expected to find all of them ordered from the smaller to the higher value.

This is bad for my application because i need that the chronological order of creation is respected and followed whenever i query the db to get all the links

```
 public function getAllUserLinks($user_id) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT l.* FROM links l, users_links ul WHERE l.id = ul.link_id AND ul.user_id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("i", $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $links = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->close();
        return $links;
    }
```

i know i could add an `ORDER BY...` to my query but this would further slow down things.

Besides, new links should be added as last row of the table, not in the middle , right?!?

Comment: There is no inherent row order in a SQL table. The engine will return the rows of a table in any way is more efficient. The only way to get an ordered set back from a `SELECT` statement is to use the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: When you fetch them using query, what is the order of result?

Comment: if you need the chronological order just do `ORDER BY created_at`

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos Seriously ? i didn't know that. i have always thought that since you insert the rows in one order, you get them in the same order

Comment: @DipanwitaKundu the order of result is exactly the one showed in the database. which is inconvenient

Comment: @Edwin or `ORDER BY id` as that is also chronological

Comment: @Edwin yeah i know, i wanted to avoid that because it would add further delay to the query. until now i thought i was doing something wrong maybe in the database settings, but i guess i will have to just use order by..

Comment: @RiggsFolly depends of what `created_at` refers to :) if is the time of inserted query or another time defined in the app. Then the order can differ. Without further information I will not do it by id.

Comment: Remember the `id` is incremented by One each time a new row is created. Therefore by definition, if you order by `id` which will definitely have an index associated with it. It is likely the retrieval time will be quicker that sorting a timestamp you have not apparently indexed.

Comment: yes yes ordering by id corresponds to ordering the links by insertion order. i can do it, even if i'm not happy with the added latency. this thing that @GiorgosBetsos said about the order in which rows are returned by the `select` statement which is different from the primary key order, is really bugging me

Comment: You have to `ORDER BY something` otherwise its not guaranteed to be ordered.

Comment: i see! well, i guess i'll surrender then :) thank you all

Answer (score 0):

So the physical order you see will be down to your clustered index, if you haven't defined one then MySQL will do it for you, from the InnoDB docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html):

> If the table has no PRIMARY KEY or suitable UNIQUE index, InnoDB internally generates a hidden clustered index on a synthetic column containing row ID values. The rows are ordered by the ID that InnoDB assigns to the rows in such a table. The row ID is a 6-byte field that increases monotonically as new rows are inserted. Thus, the rows ordered by the row ID are physically in insertion order.

I'm assuming you're using InnoDB but MyISAM would also use the clustered index to determine physical order. Some more info [here](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes) about clustered indexes.

### Edit

The comment below is correct to say clustered indexes are how data is stored and strictly speaking not how data is retrieved. In practice there's a good chance you'll find data returned in physical order if you don't specify an ORDER BY.

I was attempting to explain why the questioner might be seeing the ordering he was but I'm not saying this should be relied upon, no guarantees are given about the order of data without an ORDER BY. From the [SQL 92 spec](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) (in various places):

> If an  is not specified, then the ordering of the rows of Q is implementation-dependent

Comment: This refers to the order records are *stored* in the database which is not necessarily the order records are returned by a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that `id` is also primary key. the engine i'm using is MyISAM. Still, whenever i SELECT them the order is not by id / chronological